# USB headset not detected in Output Devices in KDE Audio Volume Settings

Tags: linux, debian, sound-card, kde-plasma-5

I'm new to this site. I've tried googling my problem but what I found doesn't relate to my problem. I have a Razar Kraken 7.1 Chroma USB headset and I can't see it in Output Devices but I can see it in Input Devices and when I click on the volume icon in the system tray it's in Capture Devices. If I unplug the headset from the USB port and then plug it back in I see it. I only have this problem on the Debian 9.0.1 liveUSB. Is there any way I can fix this? I really want to use Debian Stretch with the KDE Plasma desktop.